# Prove that the set of integers is a Borel Set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I understand the general definition of Borel Set. I also managed to prove the interval (a, b) is a Borel set. However, I'm having trouble proving mathematically that the set of integers is also a Borel Set. Gut feel says that I can use the fact that a singleton {a} is a Borel set by writing it as a countable infinite intersection of open intervals. Any help will be appreciated in systematically proving that a set of integers is actually a Borel Set.

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $\{a\}, a \in \mathbb R$ is also a Borel Set?Hence Conclude.

Comment: " a singleton {a} is a Borel set by writing it as a infinite countable unions of open intervals " hopefully this is not really what you meant.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo edited. My bad,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton set is a Borel set since each integer $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $\displaystyle \{a\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n}, a + \frac{1}{n})$, then the given set $E \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is clearly a Borel set, since the collection of Borel sets is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks. Just got a little confused by the set E in your answer :)

Comment: $E$ is just any set of integers, :)